# Oracle Text: CONTAINS is not returning any values, even though they exist in the index

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

I'm very new to Oracle, and I've created a basic application which uses Oracle Text to perform a text search on an index.

My table structure is as follows:

```
[  Table: Stores ]
------------------
store_id        PK
name           VC2
description    VC2
```

My description field then has an index assigned against it:

```
CREATE INDEX stores_desc_ctx_idx  ON stores(description) INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context;
```

I've validated in SQLDeveloper that the INDEX exists under my Index tab, however when I run a query the results returned are always null, even when I can clearly see that the data in any given row matches the input string.

**Let description A:**

```
Local GAME store in Plymouth, selling all the latest titles as well as legacy ones!
```

**let description B:**

```
Local Morrison's store in Plymouth, selling all the food you could possibly want!
```

**Let query**:

```
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE contains(description, 'GAME') > 0;
```

I would expect the result of the query to return description A, however no results are returned...what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future users who face a similar problem.

SQLDeveloper has somehow invalidated my INDEX, I simply navigated to the INDEX tab, right clicked and selected "Rebuild". Doing this re-validated the INDEX and the code now works as expected.

Comment: These indexes must be manually synchronized after table changes.  Re-building would do the same thing although may be less efficient.

Comment: CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX should do it.

Comment: Thanks Jon,  I guess I should do this in my after trigger??

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't have a lot of practical experience with it.  Running DDL in a trigger may cause some concurrency issues.  I'm not sure what the best practice is.  Maybe a scheduled job, or at the end of a large batch load?

Comment: Gotcha, I'll read into it a little more,  thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify when the full text index will be updated by the DB system using the "Parameters" syntax with the "Create index" statement.
For example the following statement creates a full text index that is updated after each commit.

```
CREATE INDEX stores_desc_ctx_idx ON stores(description) INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context PARAMETERS ('SYNC(ON COMMIT)');
```

See the oracle docs for all possible "SYNC" options